# button text change when pressed and changed back when pressed again

Tags: c#, button

so I'm using a button named "Deactivate listening" when pressed it should change the text to "Activate listening" and when pressed again it should go back to "Deactivate listening" i tried writing it using if else statement but for some reason this code doesn't work.

```
 if (BtnDeactivate.Text == "Deactivate listening")
      BtnDeactivate.Text = "Activate listening";
 else BtnDeactivate.Text = "Deactivate Listening";
```

Comment: Strings comparisons are case sensitive.

Comment: I don't think you posted enough code and I'm not sure what the error is but I can see you cased listening differently which will become a problem with this toggle statement.  I personally suggest adding a flag and using that to toggle text instead of relying on the text itself.  I also suggest using constants for your text, which would solve the case problem you're having also.

Comment: you need to disable the button before you change the text then re enable.

Comment: C# is used with multiple GUI frameworks that have a Button class. Add a tag for your UI. Also, post the complete method.  You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this;

```
{
    var deactivatedText = "Deactivate Listening";
    if (BtnDeactivate.Text == deactivatedText )
    {
        BtnDeactivate.Text = "Activate listening";
    }
    else
    {
        BtnDeactivate.Text = deactivatedText;
    }
}
```

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, OP misspelled the "Deactivate Listening" => "Deactivate listening". I Suggest text to hold in one place. So make it less error-prone. Is There any reason other than this to downvote?

Comment: Nope, seems like a reasonable solution.